# Retrieving data from the operating system and storing it in the program

Tags: c#

If a text file is stored with lots of words in it like cat, rat, hat, bat all stored in `words.txt`, a notepad how can i retrieve each word separately and get them stored in a string array `String []` MyArray using a FileStream and `StreamReader` object. It has get stored like `MyArray[0] = "cat"`, MyArray[1] = "rat".

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to read a file? How to split a string?

Comment: reading a file and then storing what's being read in an array variable. Where each word is stored at different indexes in the array using a file stream and stream reader object

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the words are separated by spaces (i.e. no punctuation, etc.), you can read the file into a string and then split it:

```
string allText = File.ReadAllText("words.txt");
string[] MyArray = allText.Split(
    new [] {" ", Environment.Newline},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If for some reason you absolutely have to use a `FileStream` and a `StreamReader`, you'd write:

```
string allText = null;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(...))  // fill in file name and other params
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        allText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
// do the string split here
```

Now, if you want to take into account punctuation and other special characters, that's a more involved problem.

Comment: Yet another "write my code for me" post rewarded with an answer.